# The complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

In solving $|z|i +2z =1$, I seem to be constantly getting two solutions while both answer key and Wolfram claim to be only one. What am I doing wrong?

Let's share the fun:

$(\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}) i  +2x +2iy =1$

leading to the system of : $$ 2y+ \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}= 0   $$ $$2x=1$$

upon solving we get $(0.5, \sqrt{1/12})$, or $(0.5, -\sqrt{1/12})$ as possible real coordinates of the complex number which may solve said equation...

Comment: We can't say what you're doing wrong unless we know what it is you're doing. Hint though: write $z=x+iy$ and group real and imaginary parts...

Comment: More context in the problem (particularly regarding what you've tried so far) greatly improves a problem statement such as this.

Comment: Remember that $|z| \geq 0$. Thus the negative root (I assume) you found is therefore not valid.

Comment: The polar form $z=r e^{i \phi}$ may also be useful.

Comment: Observe that $1-2z$ is purely imaginary. Thus $z=\frac{1-bi}{2}$. Now solve for $b$. Bear in mind that $b>0$.

Comment: what's wrong with a negtive component on the imaginary axis?

Comment: Note that $b=|z|$, hence $b \geq 0$ but $z=0$ Is not a solution, hence $ b>0$.

Comment: There are many situations where "solving" an equation or a system of equations leads to spurious solutions. Once such situation is where, at some step in your "solution", you find yourself taking the square of a square root; if so then your job is not complete until you back substitute each of your solutions, checking each one back in the original problem.

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$$2y=-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

But $\displaystyle\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge0\implies y\le0$